# How can I prefetch related objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-debug-toolbar

Assuming I have the following model with related methods:

```
class Turbine(models.Model):
    ...
    pass

def relContracts(self):
    contracts = self.contracted_turbines.all()
    return contracts

class Contract(models.Model):
    turbines = models.ManyToManyField(Turbine,related_name='contracted_turbines')

def _contracted_windfarm_name(self):
    windfarms = self.turbines.order_by().values_list("wind_farm__name", flat=True).distinct().select_related
    if len(windfarms) == 1:
        return windfarms[0]
    else:
        return ", ".join([str(x) for x in windfarms])
contracted_windfarm_name = property(_contracted_windfarm_name)

def _turbine_age(self):
    first_commisioning = self.turbines.all().aggregate(first=Min('commisioning'))['first']
    start = self.start_operation.year
    age = start - first_commisioning.year
    return age
turbine_age = property(_turbine_age)
```

Django-debug-toolbar tells me, that the functions "_contracted_windfarm_name" and "_turbine_age" result in database duplicates for each contract.

My contracts queryset is received by the following get_queryset method where I already prefetched 'turbines' for other methods succesfully:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    qs = super(ContractTableView, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True).prefetch_related('turbines', 'turbines__wind_farm')
    self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return self.filter.qs
```

I tried prefetching 'turbines__contracted_turbines' without being able to reduce the number of duplicates.

The `_contracted_windfarm_name` method is used to populate a column of a django-tables2 method as follows:

```
contracted_windfarm = dt2.Column(accessor='contracted_windfarm_name', verbose_name='Wind Farm', orderable=False)
```

Where am I mistaking? How can I prefetch the associated contracts of a turbine?

**SOLUTION: First problem**

I added a simple annotation to the queryset within the get_queryset() method:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    qs = super(ContractTableView, self).get_queryset()\
      .filter(active=True).prefetch_related('turbines', 'turbines__wind_farm')\
      .annotate(first_com_date=Case(When(turbines__commisioning__isnull=False, then=Min('turbines__commisioning'))))
    self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
    return self.filter.qs
```

This leads to a slight change in the _turbine_age() method:

```
def _turbine_age(self):
    first_commisioning = self.first_commisioning
    start = self.start_operation.year
    age = start - first_commisioning.year
    return age
turbine_age = property(_turbine_age)
```

**SOLUTION: second problem**

With the `turbines__wind_farm` being prefetched in the `get_queryset()` method, there is no need to call the `distinct()` method:

```
def _contracted_windfarm_name(self):
    windfarms = list(set([str(x.wind_farm.name) for x in self.turbines.all()]))
    if len(windfarms) == 1:
        return windfarms[0]
    else:
        return ", ".join([str(x) for x in windfarms])
contracted_windfarm_name = property(_contracted_windfarm_name)
```

All duplicated queries could be removed!

Thanks to @dirkgroten for his valuable contributions!

Comment: Your `_turbine_age` and `_contracted_windfarm_name` methods add additional db query logic to the original query: when you first `prefetch_related` you fetch `contract.turbines.all()` but then for each object, you are adding an aggregation or a distinct() clause, which forces Django to query the db again. Try moving the query logic for `first_commissioning` and `windfarms` to the model's Manager so you have that already handled by the bulk query.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please provide a suggestion, how to move the logic for `first_commisioning` and `windfarms` to the model's Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Min

class ContractManager(models.Manager):
    def with_first_commissioning(self):
        return self.annotate(first_commissioning=Min('turbines__commissioning'))

class Contract(models.Model):
    objects = ContractManager()
    ...
```

then `Contract.objects.with_first_commissioning()` returns you a Queryset with the additional `first_commissioning` value for each `Contract`. So in `Contract._turbine_age()` you can just remove the first line.

Now the windfarm names case is a bit more complex. If you're using Postgresql (which supports `StringAgg`) you could similarly add in your `ContractManager` this queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg

def with_windfarms(self):
    wind_farms = WindFarm.objects.filter('turbines__contract'=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().distinct().values('turbines__contract')
    wind_farm_names = wind_farms.annotate(names=StringAgg('name', delimiter=', ')).values('names')
    return self.annotate(wind_farm_names=Subquery(wind_farm_names))
```

then in your `_contracted_windfarm_name()` method, you can access `self.wind_farm_names` assuming you're looping through the results of the queryset (you should probably check with `hasattr` in case your method gets used in a different way).

If you're not on Postgresql, then just change the queryset to perform a `prefetch_related` and then make sure you don't add any query-related logic after that:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def with_windfarms(self):
     return self.prefetch_related(Prefetch('turbines', queryset=Turbine.objects.order_by().select_related('wind_farm').distinct('wind_farm__name')))
```

so that in your `_contracted_wind_farms` method, you can do `[str(x.wind_farm.name) for x in self.turbines]`

In both cases, I'm assuming somewhere in your views you loop through the `contracts` in the queryset:

```
for contract in Contract.objects.with_first_commissioning():
    contract._turbine_age()...

for contract in Contract.objects.with_windfarms():
    contract._contracted_windfarm_name()...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My project is based on a MySQL database, so your second solution would be applicable. I am using the `_contracted_windfarm_name` method to populate a column of a django-tables2 table: `contracted_windfarm = dt2.Column(accessor='contracted_windfarm_name', verbose_name='Wind Farm', orderable=False)`. How would you apply your solution to this problem, since I don't loop over the queryset as you assumed?

Comment: If you're just accessing one `Contract` then why worry about prefetch_related? Your original method just works fine.

Comment: It works fine, but it creates additonal queries while executing the distinct() method, as you pointed out. How can these additional queries be avoided?

Comment: Can you add the code where you’re populating the extra db column so I can think about it?

Comment: I don't know if I got you right. Could you precise, what you mean by extra db column?

Comment: I meant the code where you populate the `contracted_windfarm` column that you mentioned above (so some more context on where `dt2.Column(...)` is called).

Comment: You can find the necessary information on the Column method of django-tables2 documentation: https://django-tables2-zh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#column

Comment: Ok, I overlooked the django-tables2 thing. But basically, `Table` is iterating through the objects all the same. If the data you pass to the table is your queryset, my method should still work. Doesn't it?

Comment: I can't test if your `with_windfarms` method is working, because I can not looping over my queryset objects. Your suggestion for the `_contracted_wind_farms` methods works, if I add .all() behind self.turbines and it actually reduces the duplicated queries.

Comment: but your dt2 table is looping over the queryset, isn't it? what I mean is that if it's using the queryset, it'll call `contracted_windfarm_name` on elements of that queryset in order to assign values to the extra column, so the annotation should work and it shouldn't perform an extra query.